How to append existing csv file with output of another variable after used column range
I am writing a script to replicate folder and multiple subfolders inside it on two servers. Each folder having multiple files. I wrote below code to compare current folder names and number of files in each from Server1 (source) to Server2 (target where replication is required),
I am able to write PRODFLDFILECount variable output to .csv, what I want is to add another variable COBFLDFILECount output in same CSV file after used column range.
Desired output in CSV as below:

################# Folder count on PROD and file count in each folder #####################
`$PRODFLDFileCount = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $SRCLPRODCAS -Directory | ForEach-Object {
     [pscustomobject] @{
       'Prod Folder' = $_.Name
       'File Count' = @(Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $_.FullName -File -Recurse).Count }
      }
    $PRODFLDFileCount |Export-Csv -Path C:\Temp\data.csv -NoTypeInformation

################# Folder count on COB and file count in each folder #####################
  $COBFLDFileCount = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $TRGTLCOBCAS -Directory | ForEach-Object {
      [pscustomobject] @{
      'COB Folder' = $_.Name
      'File Count' = @(Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $_.FullName -File -Recurse).Count }
   }
     $COBFLDFileCount |Export-Csv -Append -Path C:\Temp\data.csv -NoTypeInformation`

Variable PRODFLDFileCount output:
Prod Folder     File Count
------------  -----------
test        122
dm001       13
dm002       284
dm33        322
dms0011     6

Variable COBFLDFileCount output:
COB Folder     File Count
------------  -----------
test        11
dm001       13
dm002       2
dm33        32
dms0011     0


Tried robocopy?

Using this Join-Object Module (see also: In Powershell, what's the best way to join two tables into one?): $PRODFLDFileCount | FullJoin $COBFLDFileCount or probably even more usefull: $PRODFLDFileCount | FullJoin $COBFLDFileCount -on 'Prod Folder' -eq 'COB Folder'
